# Show that the following series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f'(n)=\sum a_n, \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f'(n)}{f(n)}=\sum b_n$ converge or diverge together.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence

Let $f: (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ be a $C^2$-function (i.e. twice continuously differentiable) such that $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Show that the following series $A$ and $B$ either both converge or both diverge
$$ A = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f'(n)=\sum a_n, \quad B = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f'(n)}{f(n)}=\sum b_n.$$

If $B$ converges then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)=0$ and hence $A$ converges.

If $A$ converges then notice that $f''<0$. So $f'$ is a strict decreasing function. Lower Riemann Sum is Right Riemann Sum, Hence we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f'(n)=f'(1)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f'(n)<f'(1)+\int_{1}^{\infty}f'(x)=f'(1)+f(\infty)-f(1)=f'(1)-f(1)$$

Also Upper Riemann Sum is left Riemann Sum, Hence we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f'(n)>\int_{1}^{\infty}f'(x)=f(\infty)-f(1)=-f(1)$$

By mixing two inequalities:
$$-f(1)<A<f'(1)-f(1)$$
$$-A<f(1)<f'(1)-A$$

But this is not helping me as I can't conclude for $B$ and don't know whether $\frac{f'(n)}{f(n)}$ is increasing or not!

Comment: Why should $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)=0$ if $B$ converges?

Comment: True my mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is concave and positive, and therefore an increasing function. It follows that $L = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists as a finite value or $+ \infty$.

$f'$ is decreasing, so that $A = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f'(n)$ converges if and only if
$$
 \int_1^\infty f'(x) \, dx = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) - f(1) < \infty \, ,
$$
i.e. if $L$ is finite.

Also
$$
 \left( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)' = \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} - \left( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)^2 < 0
$$
so that the same argument can be applied to $B = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f'(n)}{f(n)}$: The series converges if and only if
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln f(x) -  \ln f(1) < \infty \, .
$$

So both series converge if and only if $L = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is finite.